# How do I ensure a single character for \ldots

Tags: symbols, punctuation

How do I ensure that `\ldots` comes out in the PDF as a single character?

I'm formatting a document for a publisher, who has given this condition in its formatting rules, but I do not know how I can do this in LaTeX.

I'm using MiKTeX 2.9

EDIT: Yes the question could be phrased as: *is it possible for `\ldots` to produce a single "triple point glyph" rather than 3 separate dots (like "..."), since that's what it currently does.*

Following the suggestion of kahen, I tried with XeLaTeX and the ellipsis character "…" as well as the `\ldots` command. Both worked and looked the same.

Comment: I don't understand your request. Could you please explain in more detail?

Comment: I think that the question is: "Does \ldots produce the single character `…` (tripple point glyph?) or three periods?"

Comment: Or rather, is it possible for `\ldots` to produce a single "triple point glyph" rather than 3 separate dots (like `...`), since that's what it current does.

Comment: If you use XeTeX, you can enter the ellipsis character `…` directly into your document, but it will *not* look the same as \ldots. I don't think there is a way to get `\ldots` as a single glyph unless your font has a properly spaced out ellipsis in it.

Comment: Check out this thread on the XeTeX mailing list as well: http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2010-December/019576.html

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command `\ldots`, which works both in text mode and in math mode, will create a single glyph in xelatex and lualatex, assuming you're using a font that knows how to set character U+2026, "Horizontal Ellipsis."

In an earlier version of this answer, I mistakenly referred to what's created in pdflatex by the `\ldots` command as a "single glyph". In fact, it's composed of three separate dots, concatenated by non-breaking whitespace. Thus, while it's not a single glyph in the narrow, technical sense, it behaves like one for typesetting purposes. For instance, it won't ever get broken up across two lines.

Comment: `\ldots` does *not* produce a single glyph in the resulting PDF file. It's produced by three peroids with manual space between them. Hence if you copy to a plain text file, you'll get `. . .` or something similar.

Comment: Is this true? I'm able to select each period/dot in `\ldots` when I view a PDF. `\ldots` defaults to either `\mathellipsis` or `\textellipsis`, depending on whether you're in math mode or not, both of which are comprised of three individual dots.

Comment: The publisher gave no other rules in regard to this. But with Xelatex and \ldots it works to produce a single glyph.

Comment: Glad that xelatex is working for you. I know there's a unicode code for "textellipsis", so that's why I was thinking that it was a single glyph.

Comment: @kahen: I've changed the answer to emphasize that whilst the output of the `\ldots` command is not a single glyph in the narrow sense of the word, this output does behave for all practical purposes like a single glyph; e.g., TeX will never split it up across lines. How it's rendered in a plain text file if you copy-and-paste it from a pdf file, while an interesting subject in itself, is importantly a function of the input encoding settings of the text editor you use.

Comment: @Werner: I've changed the answer to make clear that whereas the output of `\ldots` is *not* a single glyph when using pdflatex (although if you use either xelatex or lualatex, it'll come out as a single glyph, unicode character U+2026), in the narrow sense of the term glyph, the output of this command (in pdflatex) does behave like a single glyph for typographic purposes. For instance, TeX will never break up the dots across lines.

Comment: @Mico: That's true, typographically it is not broken. Still not sure what the publisher is after with a request such as a single-glyph requirement for `\ldots`.

Comment: @Werner: I strongly suspect the publisher cares mostly about the dots not getting broken up across lines. The OP mentioned that ellipses have to be a "single character" -- this would be satisfied by a single glyph, but also by any construct that will not ever get broken up (in the pdf file, of course).

Comment: Just to emphasize why I accepted this answer: with xelatex \ldots produces a single glyph: It can't be broken across lines AND it can only be selected and copied as a whole. When pasted in my texteditor, it produces … . So it seams that this is exactly what I had to do.

Answer (score 9):

You could use the dots family from the [MnSymbol](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/MnSymbol) package; in the following example I used `\hdots` to define a new command `\Ldots` to produce the same result as `\hdots`, but using lowered instead of centered dots (I used `\mathop` in my definition to give the symbol the spacing corresponding to a standard operator, but you could replace it with `\mathord` to get the same spacing as `\hdots`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\newcommand\Ldots{\mathop{\lower.5ex\hbox{$\hdots$}}}

\begin{document}

\[ a\hdots b \]

\[ a\Ldots b \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

This remark is on page 64 of the [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive)
:

> Also, unlike most of the other dot symbols in this document,
>   MnSymbol’s dots are defined as single characters instead of as
>   composites of multiple single-dot characters.

Comment: Unlike `\ldots`, this creates three dots which are centered vertically.

Comment: @diabonas: good point. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Some quick tests shows that using `\smash{\raisebox{-.5ex}{$\hdots$}}` pushes it down to the baseline.